# How to extract values from hashes into separate arrays?

Tags: ruby

How can i change this:

```
array_of_hash = [{"month"=>"January", "count"=>67241},
                 {"month"=>"February", "count"=>60464},
                 {"month"=>"March", "count"=>30403}]
```

To this :

```
month = ["January", "February", "March"]
count = [67241, 60464,30403]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes  i test some methods , but i am new with programming

Comment: It's always good to include your attempts, regardless of their quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to iterate the array of hashes and add the required values to two separate arrays:

```
months = []
counts = []
array_of_hash.each do |hash|
  months << hash["month"]
  counts << hash["count"]
end
```

But you could also use `each_with_object`

```
months, count = array_of_hash.each_with_object([[], []]) do |hash, accu|
  accu[0] << hash["month"]
  accu[1] << hash["count"]
end
```

or iterate twice and get the months and counts separately:

```
months = array_of_hash.map { |hash| hash["month"] }
counts = array_of_hash.map { |hash| hash["count"] }
```

Answer (score 3):

To extract a single value (e.g. `'month'`), you could use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
array_of_hash.map { |hash| hash['month'] }
#=> ["January", "February", "March"]
```

Which can be extended to return the values for both, `'month` and `'count'`:

```
array_of_hash.map { |h| [h['month'], h['count']] }
#=> [["January", 67241], ["February", 60464], ["March", 30403]]
```

There's also a method to fetch multiple values at once – [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
array_of_hash.map { |h| h.values_at('month', 'count') }
#=> [["January", 67241], ["February", 60464], ["March", 30403]]
```

The resulting array can then be rearranged via [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
array_of_hash.map { |h| h.values_at('month', 'count') }.transpose
#=> [["January", "February", "March"], [67241, 60464, 30403]]
```

The two inner arrays can be assigned to separate variables using Ruby's [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
months, counts = array_of_hash.map { |h| h.values_at('month', 'count') }.transpose

months #=> ["January", "February", "March"]
counts #=> [67241, 60464, 30403]
```

Comment: "transpose" is nice.

Comment: `array_of_hash.map(&:values).transpose` is another option.

Comment: @SagarPandya yeah, but it relies on the value order.

Answer (score 1):

```
months, counts =
  array_of_hash.
    flat_map(&:values).
    partition(&String.method(:===))
```

---

```
months, counts =
  %w|month count|.map { |key| array_of_hash.map { |h| h[key] } }
```

Comment: Your solution is always unique and always using the complete power of Ruby!

Answer (score 0):

```
month = []
count = []
array_of_hash.each do |hash|
   month << hash['month']
   count << hash['count']
end
```

Comment: Please add some explanations, avoid code only answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.